# Why doesn't my jquery code work in my project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

This is my jquery code:

```
jQuery(Document).ready(function(){
    $('#navigation > .first-column > ul > li > a').css( "border", "3px double red" );
});
```

but it doesn't work in my project. 
Why doesn't my jQuery code work in my project?

Comment: time to go to the basics bro: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: unless you have `var Document = document;` somewhere in your code, `Document` is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Document` should be `document` - javascript is case sensitive:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation > .first-column > ul > li > a').css("border", "3px double red");
});
```

As a general rule, the first thing to do when you discover your javascript code doesn't work is to check the console for an error. That will give you an idea of where in your code you should be looking.

Answer (score 1):

`Document` should be `document` in your code otherwise it will give error if you check the console.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone says: `Document` should be `document` but you also reference both jQuery and $. As you are referencing $ inside the code, you might as well reference it outside as well :)

You are better off with the shorter syntax for the document load event:

```
$(function(){
    $('#navigation > .first-column > ul > li > a').css( "border", "3px double red" );
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#navigation > .first-column > ul > li > a').css( "border", "3px double red" );
});
```

What you probably meant to do was this version (passing $ explicitly to scope it):

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#navigation > .first-column > ul > li > a').css( "border", "3px double red" );
});
```